# Delete message from outbox/inbox

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I have built an app that send an SMS Message through SmsMenager:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault()
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null,text, null, null);
```

Everything goes well. The sms is sent without any intervention of the user.
My goal now is to delete the message sent from the inbox/outbox. Is it possible?